# Update items in the Mongo db from one to several machines

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a question on what is the better strategy on updating an specific filed of every item in mongodb collection? I have a about 3 million items in the collection and all the DB is on one machine and NO sharding.

Obviously, one can get a cursor for the collection and loop through every item and update the desired field one by one but that does not seem every efficient. That is even harder to do when you want to do the field update from multiple machines to expedite things and you always have the concern of updating the same items again. I should mention that every filed update of my DB requires a http call to the internet and if I can have multiple field update going at the same time, it is more efficient.

How should I do such thing?

I am using the C# driver.

NOTE:
I do not want to update all the fields of my items with one specific value. In my scenario, every item of mine gets a different value for the desired field and the new value is calculated for that item exclusively. In other words, I probably still need to get every item and use my logic to update to the new value.

I am wondering how can I do this concurrently so that I can apply the logic on as many as items concurrently without updating an item twice?

I want to be able to do this from one process on multiple threads or from different process on multiple machines? This very much reminds of map process in the map-reduce where map-key is the object id and map-value is the update item and the reducder is an identity reducer but I am not sure if the map/reduce of MongoDb is suitable for such thing.

Comment: map reduce runs on the server and is single threaded as long as you're running a single mongod, so running it on multiple clients isn't going to help you much. Is this a one time deal, or is this something you want to do often? You might consider mongoimport.

Comment: Ogh, then that will not help then. This is an ongoing thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky situation but this approach is probably the most resource efficient

1. "find" batch (say 1,000) of documents to update that are not currently "in progress" and retrieve their _id values.
2. Run multi update on this batch to mark them as being "in progress" with a safe=true write
3. If reservation succeeded perform logic on all batch documents
4. Order batch by new field value (meaning, make lists of all documents that will end up with the same field value)
5. Per unique field value perform a HTTP request and a batch update that sets the new field value and either removes the "in progress" flag or sets the flag to "processed" depending on your functional requirements.

This way only one thread/process/machine will update a record, you have the most optimal batch updates and you can run multiple batches at the same time without one interfering with the other.

All that said true write concurrency comes from sharding and sharding alone. Nothing stops you from running 6 mongod daemons on one (fast) machine. Also, having to do a HTTP request per field value update sounds like something extremely inefficient. There's no way mongo writes (concurrent or otherwise) would ever be the bottleneck. If the HTTP request is to your own web service consider allowing bulk requests. Finally, this scenario might be the result of a schema issue. Perhaps you could make the fields you're updating now references to a smaller set of documents instead. If you provide more context I might be able to figure something out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a evolving database schema and where I continuously discover new fields and would like to add the field and relevant value to the DB. That is the primary reason that I am using mongodb as I assume, I can easily evolve my schema without hurting the existing data in the database and added the new information as time come. Am I looking at this correctly?

Comment: I used to do something similar with a presisted queue of items that need to get updated and I probably approach it like that then. Would you please elaborate on "Perhaps you could make the fields you're updating now references to a smaller set of documents instead" maybe with an example?

Comment: Well that approach is only viable in certain situations and judging from your comments I don't think it applies to yours. If you can be a bit more specific about your use case we can discuss further.

Comment: I can not explain it here in the comment. Could I possibly email you?

Comment: Also, would you please give an example of how to do #2, the multi update part? how can do an atomatic batch update of the list of items that I want to work with?

Comment: db.co.update(criteria, update, false, true). This will automically update all documents that fit "criteria". In this case that would be an $in:[batch_ids]

Comment: Great, thanks. Now that I undestand this, then what do you mean by "HTTP request and a batch update" in #5? What is th HTTP part on MongoDb side? Actually, is it possible to do "batch update" with MonogoDB too? I am mean if I update all the items in my batch and then persite the update as a batch where mongoDb will update every update in the batch? I am not asking for batch upsert but more like a batch update with the caveat that every item in the batch has a new value.

Comment: I was referring to the HTTP requests you mentioned you have to to per field value. Batch updates in the sense that you can submit multiple individual updates to MongoDB do not exist.

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thanks a million for your help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in C#, but I'm not able to test it myself:

```
var update = Update.Set("field", "new value");
collection.Update(new BsonDocument(), update, UpdateFlags.Multi, SafeMode.True);
```

Also, you might consider running this update from the server shell, which would probably be faster. This I was able to test. It took about a minute to update a million (very simple) documents with a new field. It took about 10 seconds to update those million documents again with another value of the same size (since it didn't have to reorganize things).

```
// where {} searches for all documents,
// {$set : {"field":"new value"}} specifies the field and value to update
// false is for "upsert" behavior
// true is for multi update, updates all matching documents
db.collection.update({}, {$set : {"field":"new value"}}, false, true);
```

Comment: Updated with test timing results.

Comment: isn't this for updating all the fields with one value? If so, I just added a note to the question. Would you please read that and comment again?

Comment: You could add a field called "updated", and set it to true when you update the field you're updating. Then delete it when you're done, or set it back to false. I'm not sure if it's worthwhile, but it would give you something to query against if you're doing your updates in chunks on multiple clients.